# Не находит изображение из массива при его переборе кликом на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html

нужна помощь в js. Хочу запихнуть в массив пронумерованные изображения из папки (folder), после чего нажатием на кнопку пролистывать их, первое изображение отображается так как его я указал, но остальные после клика на кнопку не находит(

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Смена картинок</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Следующий" onClick="imgsrc();">
<img id="image" src="folder/1.jpg">
<script language="javascript">
        var i=0;
        var image=document.getElementById("image");             
        var imgs= (
       function getImages(n){  
          for( var arr, array = [], i = 1; i <= n; i++ ){
            arr = new Image;
            arr.src = "folder/" + i + ".jpg";
            array.push( arr );
          };
        return array;
        }
        ());
        
        var j=imgs.length;
        function imgsrc(){
            if (i!=(j-1))
                {i++;}
        image.src=imgs[i];
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вызов `getImages` потерял аргумент, см. комментарий ниже.

```js
var i = 0;
var image = document.getElementById("image");
var imgs = (function getImages(n) {
    
  for (var arr, array = [], i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    arr = new Image();
    arr.src = "folder/" + i + ".jpg";
    array.push(arr);
  }
  return array;
})(10); //аргумент потерялся

var j = imgs.length;
function imgsrc() {
  if (i != j - 1) {
    i++;
  }
  image.src = imgs[i];
}
```